# jQuery/javascript event for select expand/collapse?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is there an event that's triggered when a select element expands/collapses?

I'm just trying to change its container's background color when it's expanded and back to original when it's collapsed.

Comment: expand -> click event. collapse -> change event

Answer (score 1):

just use css

```
select:active {
   background-color: blue;
}
```

Comment: I'll try this in a minute.

Comment: This looks like it might work but I need to change the background of the container when the select is active so in a `<div><select></select></div>` structure I need to change the div's background when the select is active because the div is transparent (because of reasons)

Comment: I have tried that and it works when the selected valu actually changes but doesn't work when you select the same value, click on the select or when you click somewhere else and the select collapses.

Comment: worked with a combination of click and blur: http://jsfiddle.net/WZLDa/2/. You should put it in the answer and I'll mark it for you.

Comment: cool, the only downside is it won't work when selected via keyboard

Comment: I can live with that for the time being.

Comment: hm, there's a problem now. The blur part doesn't trigger on first click outside of the select, only on the second. Also only on firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Nope there is not, but you could trigger your own event with the [trigger](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) function in jQuery, this will trigger a custom event that you can define.

You can also just check if the collapsed div [is visible](http://api.jquery.com/is/), [add a class](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) or use the [data](http://api.jquery.com/data/) API.

Or just use [CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/%3aactive) as David Fregoli states.